# Accidentally deleted rc.local on Linux Mint 17.3

Tags: linux-mint

I accidentally deleted `/etc/rc.local`. Now I'm trying to get it back. But I can't find it on the setup medium.

What is stored in this file? And how to get it back?

Comment: [Purpose and typical usage of /etc/rc.local](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/49626)

Comment: @DavidPostill Thanks for the helpful link and the hin to a more suitable stackexchange site. Actually, I wasn't aware of that site.

Comment: I'm not what the `systemd` tag is for. Linux Mint 17.3 is based on Ubuntu 14.04, which does not use systemd.

Comment: @MarkStosberg I tried to find out what this file is for and stubled upon some sites the linked it with systemd, so I thought that are somehow related. I'll remove that tag. Thanks.

Comment: @PVitt The relationship is that with `systemd`, `rc.local` is not necessary, but some systems that are based on `systemd`  still support `rc.local` for backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the absence of the file is causing a problem, the default contents are typically a bash script that just returns a successful exit code:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local - executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel
#
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
exit 0;
```

As the comment in the file suggests, it's used to run extra stuff you might want late in the boot process. All system critical services are started elsewhere. This is there for system owners like you to modify if you want to.

Comment: To be honest, I was too afraid to reboot to see whether it causes any problems. But according to your and David's answer, it shouldn't be that much of an issue. Thanks anyway.